# What is the difference between Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developer and Eclipse for Mobile Developer?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-juno

This is in relation to latest `Juno or 4.2` release of `Eclipse`. I am an `Android` programmer and no expert on `IDE`. I wish to know for Android programming should I use `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developer` or `Eclipse for Mobile Developer` and what are the major differences between the two?

I have read the `faq` and this question will fall in the category of `software tools commonly used by programmers`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The core Eclipse IDE is the heart of all Eclipse IDEs. Eclipse EE or Eclipse Mobile is nothing but the extended versions of the IDE.

Like Eclipse EE contains supporting plugins for EE developers, where Mobile edition contains basic mobile plugins. This is same like as downloading basic Eclipse IDE & then installing ADT to it. Here you do it manually, where the versions comes with the specific plugins as ready solution.

Comment: Great Answer, but which is best for Android development  "Java EE", "classic 4.2", "Java" or "Mobile"...

Comment: for android its important of presence of ADT, so 1st choice: download Java/Mobile & install ADT. 2nd: use classic. **Using EE is not a solution**, because it will give you the power of EE, which is useless for you. better follow Google's suggestion :)

Comment: If you want to code both native and HTML/Javascript apps then I would suggest going with 'Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers' and adding the ADT plugin.  The 'Eclipse for Mobile Developers' is fantastic out of the box for native(Java) development but does not offer javascript/html IDE support.